# Firebase: Unable to send OTP

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I have a react component below which should send **OTP** after **re-captcha** has been resolved and it fires a callback. But the **callback** doesn’t seem to fire.

```
import React from 'react';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxx',
  projectId: 'xxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
  appId: 'xxx',
  measurementId: 'xxx',
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function App() {
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    window.reCaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: function (response) {
        // callback is not being fired
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input />
      <button id="sign-in-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As per the docs the **callback** will be fired, inside which we can call the function to send OTP.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors in console.